# How can I add a footnote that includes a bibliographic reference?

Tags: footnotes, markdown

I'm a new LaTex and Markdown user. I'm trying to include a bibliographic reference in my footnote, but when I export it my reference doesn't appear and the quote command comes out ([@MyReference]).

Do you have any idea how to do it?

Thank you!

Example :

In LaTex = 
\footnote{some text some text some text some text  [@MyReference] some text some text [@MyReference2]}

In pDF = 
1 some text some text some text some text  [@MyReference] some text some text [@MyReference2]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! In LaTeX citing a bibliographic reference is done with the `\cite` command (and not with the `[@ref]` syntax, which I assume is Markdown).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 

I tried this command= \footnote{text text \cite{Reference1} and text text \cite{Reference2}}

Results on PDF:
1 text text [?] and text text [?]

Do you have any idea what a mistake I made?

Comment: After you process the file with LaTeX, you have to run a separate program to read the references from your bibliography file which will replace the question marks with the actual references on the next LaTeX run. See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management#Getting_current_LaTeX_document_to_use_your_.bib_file for more explanation. Depending on which LaTeX editor you use this can be automated such that you press a 'compile' button or type a single command and the editor will run all necessary tools and compilation steps in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally this worked on Markdown:
^[blah blah blah blah [@Ref1] and blah blah blah [@Ref2]]